# Crossed pin in the jumper

Tags: orcad

Could you tell me why do I see the crossed rectangle on the 3V3 pin?

The element that applies to 3V3_PSU and 3V3 pins is a jumper.

Do I need to worry about it?

[image]

Comment: Which EDA software is it?

Comment: Most likely this means there is another explicit connection between layers at that place. You might have moved the jumper right on top of an existing via.

Comment: @RohatKılıç OrCAD 17.4

Comment: At a guess, I'd say this pin was connected to the 3V3 plane on the power plane layer.